# Firebase Messaging Difference between callbacks

Tags: firebase, flutter, callback, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a hard time finding any site that clearly explains the differences between the firebase messaging callbacks of onBackgroundMessage, onLaunch, and onResume. These words may seem common sense but they are not. I need a clear explanation of the differences between these callbacks. In what situations are these callbacks used?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Firebase Cloud Messaging is not only used for sending Notifications. 
With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients: 
**Notification messages** sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically. 
**Data messages**, which are handled by the client app.
[image]

This Official Documentation explains it all. 
**Functions Reference:** https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages

**Message Types Reference:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: I need to understand the differences. For example, I know that "onBackgroundMessage is triggered when only there is no notification on the payload. if there a notification on the payload what it does is it sends shows you notification on the system tray." But in what situation is onLaunch and onResume triggered?